# Swift- shifting text field issue

Tags: swift, uitextfield, keyboard-events

I have 2 text fields both placed on top of a image view. The bottom text field is supposed to shift up when the keyboard appears. When the image view is empty the bottom text field shifts up as expected, but when image is present in image view, the bottom text field doesn't shift up. when executing can see with help of print statements that keyboardWillShow function is not executing. can anyone help here?

Following is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var actualImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!
    var activeTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        topTextField.delegate = self
        bottomTextField.delegate = self

        //Animations
          topTextField.isHidden = true
          bottomTextField.isHidden = true
          shareButton.isEnabled = false
          deleteButton.isEnabled = false


        let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
    //Editing text Fields
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField
    }
    @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
            print("keyboarddidshow")

        if activeTextField != nil {

            let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
            let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
            let keyboardY = self.view.frame.size.height  - keyboardSize.height
            let textFieldY: CGFloat! = self.activeTextField.frame.origin.y


            if self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0{

                if textFieldY > (keyboardY - 80){

                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,delay:0.0,options:UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - (textFieldY - (keyboardY - 80)), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification){

        print("switch field keyboard will hide")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,delay:0.0,options:UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)}, completion: nil
        )

    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    //share button pressed
    @IBAction func sharePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        topTextField.borderStyle = .none
        topTextField.borderStyle = .none
        let image: UIImage = generateMemedImage()
        let shareImage = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, topTextField,bottomTextField], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(shareImage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    //allow selecting image from photo library
    @IBAction func selectFromGallery(_ sender: Any) {
        let gallery = UIImagePickerController()
        gallery.delegate = self
        gallery.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func selectFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        let gallery = UIImagePickerController()
        gallery.delegate = self
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            gallery.sourceType = .camera
            present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
             displayAlert(title: "Camera not available", message: "")

        }

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        actualImage.image = selectedImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        topTextField.isHidden = false
        bottomTextField.isHidden = false
        shareButton.isEnabled = true
        deleteButton.isEnabled = true
        topTextField.text = " "
        bottomTextField.text = " "

    }
    @IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        actualImage.image = nil
        topTextField.isHidden = true
        bottomTextField.isHidden = true
        shareButton.isEnabled = false
        deleteButton.isEnabled = false
        topTextField.text = " "
        bottomTextField.text = " "
    }

    //display alert
    func displayAlert(title: String, message:String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {

        // Render view to an image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 375, height: 517), false, 0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: -75, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return memedImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show the camera or the gallery, `viewDidDisappear` is called, which removes your subscription to the notifications. Perhaps you should subscribe to the notifications in `viewDidAppear` like thus:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```